# Integrating Groovy RootLoader with Java 8 SystemClassLoader

Tags: java, groovy, classloader

The following is deep inside a library I use.  In 2015 this worked with Groovy 2.3 and early versions of 2.4, probably with Java 6 or 7!  I wanted to update to Java 8 before trying to modify for Java9+.

```
final class DynamicClassLoader extends ClassLoader {

    final NodeID originatingNode;
    NetChannelOutput requestClassData;
    NetChannelInput classDataResponse = NetChannel.net2one();
    final Hashtable classes = new Hashtable();

    DynamicClassLoader(NodeID originator, NetChannelLocation requestLocation) {
        super(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());
        this.originatingNode = originator;
        this.requestClassData = NetChannel.one2net(requestLocation);
    }
    ...
}
```

When I try to invoke the code from Groovy I get the following error:
`org.codehaus.groovy.tools.RootLoader cannot be cast to jcsp.net2.mobile.DynamicClassLoader`

The Point where this is called from is given in the following code at the line indicated by **

```
    public byte[] filterTX(Object obj)
        throws IOException
    {
        ClassLoader loader = obj.getClass().getClassLoader();
        byte[] bytes = this.internalFilter.filterTX(obj);
        if (loader == ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader() || loader == null)
        {
            DynamicClassLoaderMessage message = new DynamicClassLoaderMessage(Node.getInstance().getNodeID(),
                    (NetChannelLocation) ClassManager.in.getLocation(), bytes);
            byte[] wrappedData = this.internalFilter.filterTX(message);
            return wrappedData;
        }
        **DynamicClassLoader dcl = (DynamicClassLoader)loader;**
        DynamicClassLoaderMessage message = new DynamicClassLoaderMessage(dcl.originatingNode,
                (NetChannelLocation) ClassManager.in.getLocation(), bytes);
        byte[] wrappedData = this.internalFilter.filterTX(message);
        return wrappedData;
    }
```

After discussion with the Groovy community I discoverd that the problem lay in the way the Intellij invokes Groovy scripts.  The code works in Eclipse without any problem.  In Intellij it was necessary to create a jar artifact for each of the scripts I wanted to run in parallel, which I could then run from a command line interface. I recoded the application in Java 8 and it worked with no problem.  Hope that helps.

Comment: what is the question? should we guess the line where error occurs?

Comment: I have added the method from where the line where the error occurs, sorry to have omitted it in the first instance

Comment: ok, but the answer is obvious - the variable `loader` contains `RootLoader` that could not be cast to `DynamicClassLoader`. You have to debug your code. There is not enough info to suggest smth